# How to get the month and year from the past date untill now JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, generate

I'm trying to figure out how to get combinations of year and month from the past date up till now.

So lets say, the past date is given as

```
const date = "December 2019"
```

Then I need an array

```
const arrayOfMonths = [ "April 2020", "March 2020", "February 2020", "January 2020", "December 2019"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: at least show us what you have tried and we can build up from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript **Date** objects and a while loop.

Just subtract a month from the current month till you get to the date you want.

Something like this should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/wsf61jpk/5/

```
var date="December 2018";
var result=[];

//set both start and end date to first date of the month
const end_date = new Date(date.replace(" ", " ,1 "));
const start_date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);


while(end_date<=start_date){

result.push(start_date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' , year: 'numeric'}));
start_date.setMonth(start_date.getMonth() - 1);

}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Returns an empty Array.

Comment: `console.log(end_date)`. It's invalid in Firefox. Should be `const end_date = new Date('December 1, 2018');`

Comment: Why `.split()` twice? Store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

i did it using by leveraging the javascript date functions

```
var oldDate = "December 2019";
var old = new Date(Date.parse(oldDate));
var today = new Date();
var yearsCount= today.getFullYear() - old.getFullYear();
var monthsArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i<=yearsCount;i++){
for(var j = 0; j<12;j++){
//skipping the months before the month in old date and the after the month in the current day
if(i==0 && j<old.getMonth()) continue;
if(i==yearsCount && j>today.getMonth()) continue;
// creating a new date in the format : mm-dd-yyyy (with dd=01) 
var newDate = new Date((j+1)+"-01-"+(old.getFullYear()+i))
//using to localestring to transfrom the date created into format : month year
var newmonth = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long',year:'numeric' });
//pushing to the array
monthsArr.push(newmonth);
}
}
console.log(monthsArr);
```

there is a room for improvement but it gets the job done

Answer (score 1):

This function is generating a list of the months and years as in example you provided. Note that input is expecting string of format `MONTH FULLYEAR` and any other format of the strings most likely will produce wrong results. Having said that I'd suggest to pass `Date` object or timestamp if it's possible

```js
function generateMonthsAndYears(startingFromDateString) {
  const cur = new Date(`15 ${startingFromDateString}`)
  const untilDateString = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth()+1, 15).toDateString();

  const result = [];

  for(; untilDateString !== cur.toDateString(); cur.setMonth(cur.getMonth()+1))
    result.push(cur.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }))

  return result;
}

console.log(generateMonthsAndYears("December 2018"))
```